# Python decoding UTF-16 from output of struct.unpack()

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-16

I can't figure out where I went wrong on this.

Here's the piece of data I'm trying to decode.

```
('2','\x00','2','\x00','5','\x00','0','\x00',
 'P','\x00','i','\x00','n','\x00','O','\x00','V','\x00',
 'E','\x00','m','\x00','p','\x00','t','\x00','y','\x00')
```

Here's the piece of code:

```
s = bytes(struct.unpack('28c',fld_desc)).decode('utf-16')
```

Instead of getting the string `'2250PinOVEmpty'`, I got this... very strange string of symbols:

```
⠧㈧Ⱐ❜砰〧Ⱐ✲✬‧屸〰✬‧㔧Ⱐ❜砰〧Ⱐ✰✬‧屸〰✬‧倧Ⱐ❜砰〧Ⱐ❩✬‧屸〰✬‧渧Ⱐ❜砰〧Ⱐ❏✬‧屸〰✬‧嘧Ⱐ❜砰〧Ⱐ❅✬‧屸〰✬‧洧Ⱐ❜砰〧Ⱐ❰✬‧屸〰✬‧琧Ⱐ❜砰〧Ⱐ❹✬‧屸〰✩
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Translate that strange symbols using Google Translate and see what you get ... :) ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `fld_desc` is indeed simply the byte string `'2\x002\x005\x000\x00P\x00i\x00n\x00O\x00V\x00E\x00m\x00p\x00t\x00y\x00'` and this is python 2, you just need to do

```
>>> fld_desc.decode('UTF-16-LE')
u'2250PinOVEmpty'
```

---

Where you did go wrong is that you need *not* use `struct.unpack` here at all. And if you do, then you'd have to note that `struct.unpack` returns a tuple of characters:

```
>>> struct.unpack(fld_desc)
('2', '\x00', '2', '\x00', '5', '\x00', '0', '\x00', 'P', '\x00', 'i', '\x00', 
 'n', '\x00', 'O', '\x00', 'V', '\x00', 'E', '\x00', 'm', '\x00', 'p', '\x00', 
 't', '\x00', 'y', '\x00')
```

which fed to `bytes` (which after all is synonym for `str` in python 2), makes it into a new string

```
"('2', '\\x00', '2', '\\x00', '5', '\\x00', '0', '\\x00', 'P', '\\x00', 'i', '\\x00', 'n', '\\x00', 'O', '\\x00', 'V', '\\x00', 'E', '\\x00', 'm', '\\x00', 'p', '\\x00', 't', '\\x00', 'y', '\\x00')"
```

Which decoded does look like mostly string of CJK characters and pictograms

> "✨✲尧へ✰㈧Ⱗ✠硜〰Ⱗ✠✵尧へ✰〧Ⱗ✠硜〰Ⱗ✠❐尧へ✰椧Ⱗ✠硜〰Ⱗ✠❮尧へ✰伧Ⱗ✠硜〰Ⱗ✠❖尧へ✰䔧Ⱗ✠硜〰Ⱗ✠❭尧へ✰瀧Ⱗ✠硜〰Ⱗ✠❴尧へ✰礧Ⱗ✠硜〰⤧"

in little endian (UTF-16-LE), and

> "⠧㈧Ⱐ❜砰〧Ⱐ✲✬‧屸〰✬‧㔧Ⱐ❜砰〧Ⱐ✰✬‧屸〰✬‧倧Ⱐ❜砰〧Ⱐ❩✬‧屸〰✬‧渧Ⱐ❜砰〧Ⱐ❏✬‧屸〰✬‧嘧Ⱐ❜砰〧Ⱐ❅✬‧屸〰✬‧洧Ⱐ❜砰〧Ⱐ❰✬‧屸〰✬‧琧Ⱐ❜砰〧Ⱐ❹✬‧屸〰✩"

in big endian (UTF-16-BE).

Comment: Thank you! Yours is a very clear explanation on where I did go wrong. Although you did not specify a code to solve the problem, from your answer I can quickly intuit the solution. I'm marking yours as _THE_ answer.

Comment: I don't think that neither, the symptoms evidenced are because of needless `struct.unpack()` on a data that would have been decodable as is.

Answer (score 4):

Join those characters, then decode it:

```
>>> data = ('2','\x00','2','\x00','5','\x00','0','\x00',
...         'P','\x00','i','\x00','n','\x00','O','\x00','V','\x00',
...         'E','\x00','m','\x00','p','\x00','t','\x00','y','\x00')
>>> ''.join(data).decode('utf-16')
u'2250PinOVEmpty'
```

Comment: Thanks! That really solved my problem. But even though @Antti did not provide a solution, he has provided a very good answer & explanation to my question "Where did I go wrong". I still vote up your answer because it cuts to the chase.